# Evaluate asserts after exception has taken place?

Tags: java, error-handling, testng, runtimeexception

Version: testng-6.8.8.jar

This test runs green:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = { NullPointerException.class })
public void shouldTestNGIgnoreAssertsAfterExceptionThrown() throws Exception {
  String iAmNull = null;
  int length = iAmNull.length();
  assertEquals(0, 1);
}
```

Any config file or other options
to continue and evaluate asserts after the exception has taken place ?

Comment: TestNG is not able to know you have another assertions after the exception. You have to use try/catch in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite your test.
For example:

```
@Test
public void shouldTestNGIgnoreAssertsAfterExceptionThrown() {
  String iAmNull = null;
  boolean hasNpe = false;
  try {
    int length = iAmNull.length();
  } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
    hasNpe = true;
  }
  assertTrue(hasNpe);
  assertEquals(0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with TestNG. This is about how Java works (and should work). Any method call on null ( `<nullObject>.someMethod()` ) causes NullPointerException to be thrown. If you don't catch it in your method, it get's propagated up the call stack. If it's not handled anywhere, execution ends with stack trace.